# Undo git reset --hard and git push -f by using this strategy?

Tags: git, github

Can I undo a git reset --hard  && git push -f origin master by having someone else who hasn't pulled in these changes run a "git push -f origin master" to change the original "git push -f origin master" that was executed first?

Comment: Can this strategy at least override the first "git push -f origin master"?

Comment: Do you have another copy of the repository ?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question means. It is a shared repo. More than one person are working on it together. My plan is to have one of those ppl run "git push -f origin master" to undo my "git reset --hard" command.

Comment: OK, If you break origin repository by anyway, you can create the bare repository from clean local repo by `git init --bare` and push as a new repository you may exchange them, and remove broken repository, all your history would be remain same, is that solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using a 'star' topology, that is one central repository and each developer pushes/fetches to/from that one.

It depends on when that person merged the common branch.

A safer way would be to first have anyone do `git push -f origin origin/master:master`, and than everyone (except you) do `git push origin origin/master:master` (without -f).

The first push will discard your commit, and leave the branch at state that person last fetched. And then everyone pushes what they think was the latest master. This is easier than checking beforehand who had the latest source.

Why `git push -f origin origin/master:master` and not simply `git push -f origin master`? The latter pushes my local branch. Theformer pushes what I believe to be correct for the remote version. So if I `git fetch` on a regular basis, but never `git merge` that to my local master, the first version will correctly handle this.

Actually there's an even better way of handling this. Most probably (as it's the default) you can use `git reflog` to browse the history of branch. Every commit you've created, including those that are no longer 'visible' because amended, rebased, whatever. You can dig through this to get the commit hash before your accidental `git reset --hard`, do `git reset --hard $hash` and `git push -f origin master` yourself.

Better yet, always, **always** triple-check before pushing with `-f`. Or consider banning this altogether.